# Can't get custom posts by custom taxonomies, but if I use a hook I can. How to get array of these posts?

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry in advance for my english.

I'm trying to get the custom posts array by custom taxonomies. But I can only do `print_r` on the `add_action('init', ...)`. Is there a way to return the posts array? Or can I only do a query to the db?

Here's my function:

```
function get_portfolio_posts()
    {
        $tax_query = 
            [
                'relation' => 'AND', // only posts that have both taxonomies will return.
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'project-type',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'mobile',
                ],
                [
                    'taxonomy' => 'project-industry',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'health-fitness',
                ],
            ];

        $posts = get_posts([
            'post_type' => 'portfolio',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => $tax_query,
        ]);

        return $posts;
    }
```

What I do:

```
print_r($posts = get_portfolio_posts()); // doesn't work: array()
```

But this works:

```
add_action('init', function(){
    print_r($posts = get_portfolio_posts());  // this worked out: not empty array. But I need to return an array
})
```

Obviously the taxonomies are registered after I do 'get_posts(...)'. Thanks for any advice or help!

Comment: Several points i see in your code snippet right off the bat! First, i see an extra pair of `[ ]` right before `'relation' => 'AND'` begins. You don't need that extra pair! Also the name of your function is `get_portfolio_posts` but what you used on the `init` hook is called `count_portfolio_posts()`. If you need the post objects, then why are you counting them? Can you please clarify what's going on? What exactly do you need?

Comment: Hi, please write a summarized title and put the rest of the explanation in the body. Goodluck 

Comment: Sorry guys, I fixed my question! Still only works on the hook...